# Can extremely long radiowaves be used in astronomy?

Tags: astronomy, radio, radio-frequency

If some can pass the atmosphere,can they be used in astronomy or are there any big limits?

Comment: If your question would be closed, re-ask this on http://astronomy.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Actually, if it gets closed, it's better to fix it up and then get it reopened. If it's closed for some reason here, it would probably be closed for the same reason there.

Comment: For what purpose would you want them to be used? What information do you hope to extract?

Answer (score 2):

Certainly they *can* be used, but the size of the antenna gets completely out of control. You may have noticed that radio telescopes are much bigger than optical telescopes, and the images they produce are not nearly as detailed.

For a receiver/antenna/lens working at wavelength $\lambda$ and diameter d, its ability to distinguish between ("resolve") two points is determined by the Rayleigh Criterion, and the angular separation (in radians) is given by $$\theta = 1.22\frac{\lambda}{d}$$

Since you have used the term "extremely long", let's use Extremely Low Frequency (ELF) as an example. [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_low_frequency) has a frequency range of 3 to 30 Hz, and a wavelength range of 100,000 to 10,000 km. So at the shortest wavelength of the range, 10,000 km, an antenna the size of the earth (12,600 km) would have a resolution of $$\theta = 1.22(\frac{10,000}{12,600}) = 1$$ or about 60 degrees.

I think you'll agree that this is not likely to be considered useful.

It's true that there are shorter RF wavelengths, and you can do the math for wavelengths of your choice. But almost any astronomical work requires very small angular resolutions, which in turn requires very large d for almost any choice of RF wavelength.

Answer (score 2):

The universe is not transparent to extremely low frequency radio waves. The interplanetary medium is charged, there are free electrons and protons (a plasma) that will screen electric fields. They can keep up with screening an oscillating field as long as it doesn't oscillate much faster than the natural oscillation frequency of the plasma when it is perturbed, the so-called [plasma frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_oscillation). For the interplanetary medium the plasma frequency is about 30 KHz, so below this frequency radio waves will not propagate over long distances through our solar system.